# install mapguide 6.5 on windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, mapguide

How can I install mapguide 6.5 on windows 7 ?
 i have problem to set a datasource in mapguide outer. do i need another software or application to install this version of mapguide in win 7 64bit? 
please help .

Comment: Try Mapguide Open Source V 2.6 with Mapguide Maestro 6.03

Answer (score 2):

I believe autodesk has stopped supporting 6.5 awhile ago. Please consider upgrading to Mapguide Opensource or Enterprise instead.